# How to store Configatron persistently, after Ruby app has run

Tags: ruby, configatron

I'm pretty new to Ruby (though not to programming) and am trying to create a persistent config. Though I thought using [Configatron](https://github.com/markbates/configatron) would automatically make my config persistent, it does not seem to be the case. How would I make this persistent throughout multiple runs? Should I store this to a file? If so, how? I would think a `~/.myapp` file might be good?

Answer (score 0):

### Persistence in Rails

If you're using Ruby on Rails, you need to [modify your initializers](https://github.com/markbates/configatron#rails) for this gem:

- `app/config/configatron/defaults.rb`
- `app/config/configatron/{development,test,production}.rb`

### Persistence Without Rails

#### Ruby Modules

If you're using Ruby itself, rather than the Rails framework, then you need to persist your configuration as a Ruby module (e.g. `require "my_configuration"`) or serialize the Configatron class if it *can* serialized. It looks like the goal of the gem is to avoid serialization, so requiring a module that contains your configuration as executable code seems to be the canonical approach for this gem.

#### Serialization

I don't use this gem myself, so you'll have to experiment with serializers to see if they work for your use case. For serialization, I'd recommend using one of:

- [YAML::Store](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html)
- [PStore](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/PStore.html)
- [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Marshal.html)

However, if you're using serialization to save and load your configuration, I'm not entirely sure why you'd need this gem in the first place. Your mileage may certainly vary.